# display order or sorting of typed parameters prompted for review at run of custom build

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

**Problem:**

Our build configuration to deploy requires a small number of typed parameters to allow for exclusion/inclusion of some service deploys.  The parameters are set to prompt for review and the build is triggered manually from teamcity's button to run custom build.

I haven't yet found any documentation for (or hackish example of) ordering or sorting rules that TeamCity uses to display those typed parameters.

As a quick sketch of an example, we're hoping to display this:

```
1. Stop service X
2. Start service X
3. Stop service Y
4. Start service Y
```

Or:

```
1. Stop service X
2. Stop service Y
3. Start service X
4. Start service Y
```

*Note:* the actual order of the build *steps* is fine and is not part of the objective here.  We don't need to re-order those; I'm hoping to avoid user error by keeping either the services grouped together or the choices grouped together.

It almost seems that the run custom build's dialog is ordered by the internal id (or creation time) of each parameter.

We're not using TeamCity's internal database but rather a MySql installation on the same host; we're open to the option of re-ordering the parameters directly in the database if necessary.

Is there another way to influence the sorting or display order of these parameters when prompting the user for their review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest one of these approaches:

1. Removing parameters at all and creating separate build for specific action: the builds are sorted alphabetically, so you can order then how you want. Besides that you could trigger each build automatically without worrying about selecting some parameters, you will see who and when did specific action for specific service (when you have a single build you have to take a look at parameters or logs to get this information).
2. If you need parameters and would like to select them, then most obvious choice is Select box from [Typed Parameters](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Typed+Parameters). You can change the order in build configuration and that should automatically make correct order in the UI
3. You can try my plugin for [dynamic select parameters](https://github.com/grundic/teamcity-web-parameters) -- this way you can control order of the parameters from remote service.

Comment: We have individual configs to build.  The single-build-with-parameters solves the order of services down, deployed, updated, and so on.  I will try your plugin though, it looks promising.